# .NET Core - 415 Unsupported Media Type (HTTP POST)

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, .net-core, axios

I'm trying to do an HTTP POST to my backend. If I use `"Content-Type": "application/json"` I get a CORS issue. The CORS issue is only with the HTTP POST, all the HTTP GETs are working fine. So I set it to `"Content-Type": "text/plain"` and it seems to solve the issue. However, now I am getting the `415 Unsupported Media Type` error when doing the HTTP POST. This is my config:

**Axios**

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

export const axiosRequestConfiguration: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL,
  responseType: "json",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    //"Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Content-Type": "text/plain",
  },
};
```

**.NET Core**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var origins = Configuration.GetSection("AllowSpecificOrigins").GetChildren().Select(o => o.Value).ToArray();

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "Payload View API",
        });
    });

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
            builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .WithOrigins(origins)
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization", "WWW-Authenticate");
            });
    });
```

**Endpoint**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SubmitFeedback([FromBody] Feedback feedback)
{
    if (feedback == null) return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);

    try
    {
        _feedbackService.SubmitFeedback(feedback);

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex.StackTrace);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try this from Postman (taking CORS out of the equation), does the POST work using the "application/json" content-type?

Comment: I cannot use Postman because I am using Windows Authentication but with swagger it works fine

Comment: Could it be related to this Axios issue where if you don't include data in your post then axios clears the "Content-Type"?  (Your axios code above has no data property, so I wasn't sure).  https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86  Workaround is to provide an empty data element (data: {}).

Comment: But I am including data in my post, so I don't understand

Comment: Since you don't show the actual axios call to your API, I wasn't sure if this issue could be relevant.  Sorry, I worded my comment above poorly.